# Continuously differentiable and weak partial derivatives

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

$A=\{f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R | f \text{ is continuously differentiable}\}$

$B=\{f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R | f \text{ has weak partial derivatives}\}$

I think that $B \subset A$ is true. Am I right?

Comment: is your question if weak derivatives are automatically continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is continuously differentiable. Then the partial derivatives exists and are continuous, hence $L^1_{\text{loc}}$ and the weak derivative are well defined.

A weak derivative $v$ of $f$ with respect to $x_i$ satisfies, for every test function $\phi$ :

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}  f \partial_{x_i} \phi = - \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} v \phi.$$

But since $\partial_{x_i} f$ is well defined (in its usual sense), integrating by parts shows that taking $v = \partial_{x_i} f$ a.e. is enough.

To sum up : a continuously differentiable function necessarily has weak partial derivatives, so $A \subset B$. And of course it is a proper subset (consider the absolute value). Meaning that functions with weak derivative does not necessarily have continuous derivatives (it may not have -usual- derivatives at all). Note to finish that weak derivatives coincide with derivatives as soon as $f$ is differentiable (you do not need continuity of the derivatives).

Comment: You proved that $A \subset B$ and wrote $B \subset A$,

Comment: Thank you. Went too fast

Comment: The heaviside function is not weakly differentiable, its derivative is a distribution

Comment: Hmm, seems like doing math at 7am is definitely not a good idea for me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample - $\sqrt{|x|}$ as a function $\mathbb R^1 \to \mathbb R$ is once weakly differentiable and is not $C^1$

Comment: I wonder why you put a square root while it was enough without it, for pedagogy purposes ? It seems you want to make a point on some subtle thing but I cannot get it.

Comment: @nicomezi well...tbh I was going to give the standard example in $n>1$ of a spike $1/|x|^\alpha \notin L^\infty$ nevermind $C^0$ or $C^1$ that was nonetheless still in some $W^{1,p}_{loc}$. So the fractional power stayed from that line of thinking. Also the failure of being $C^1$ is a little more drastic...but you're right.

Comment: Ho I see. I am not right or wrong, it was just out if curiosity since I may have missed something ( I need to wake up a little bit, as you have seen).